# How do I access Shared Data Extension using Server Side Javascript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, shared-activities

I am trying to access Shared Data Extension using Server Side Javascript. I am trying the below stated code but it is not working. Even though the Data Extension has more than 1 record, the length I am getting is when I try to look up records on DE is coming as 0.

```
var journeyConfigurationDE = DataExtension.Init("ENT.Journey_Configuration_DE_NL");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code for using the JavaScript core library to access a shared data extension.

I can confirm that the following works which uses SSJS Platform functions:

```
<script runat="server">
     var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('ENT.My Favorite Shared DE','Key','1');
     Platform.Response.Write(dataRows.length);
     if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
          for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
               Platform.Response.Write(dataRows[i]["Key"]);
          }
     }
</script>
```

Reference: [**Interacting with Data Extensions Using the Function Object**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/conteudo/javascript_do_servidor/guia_de_sintaxe/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/interacting_with_data_extensions_using_the_function_object/)